# Problem with stale ActiveRecord association in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models: Site, Subscription, Plan:

**Site**

```
has_one     :subscription
has_one     :plan, :through => :subscription
```

**Subscription**

```
belongs_to  :site
belongs_to  :plan
```

**Plan**

```
has_many  :subscriptions
```

In my SubscriptionsController I'm handing a POST by first loading the relevant objects:

```
@site = current_user.site
@subscription = @site.subscription
@plan = @subscription.plan
```

Unfortunately, if @subscription.plan is modified and saved before the POST then that change is not reflected in @site unless I perform a @site.reload at the beginning of my controller method.

ex.

```
eval @subscription
> #<Subscription id: 6115, site_id: 5634, plan_id: 342, ... <== GOOD

eval @site.plan
> #<Plan id: 337, ... <== BAD

eval @subscription.site.plan
> #<Plan id: 342, ... <=== GOOD

eval @site.reload
eval @site.plan
> #<Plan id: 342,... <== GOOD
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

There are two viable answers below, but I'm going to hold off on accepting either of them until I learn more about the 'touch' option that Jesse mentioned (which, unfortunately, doesn't work for me....yet).

Comment: Your associations look incorrect to me. Is the relationship between Site and Plan one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: The associations are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just how Active Record is designed. It tries not to hit your database too often and will prefer to read from memory than the database.

Preferably, you should be modifying the Plan **through** the Site rather than separately from it. Basically, if you're reading by going through the @site, you should be writing through @site, as well.

If that's not possible or desirable, you may want to have a small helper method checking the updated_at column to see if the record has changed and reloading Site if it did. If it sounds hacky, that's because it is. :)

Comment: That makes sense. The 'touch' option that Jesse mentioned in his answer seemed like a viable approach, but it doesn't work for me. Until I figure that out I'll stick with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You may find success with the :touch method on your relations.

The general idea is that if I update a comment, the posts's updated_at will get updated as well. I think this will translate to your @site record in memory.

```
class Site
  has_one     :subscription, :touch=>true
  has_one     :plan, :through => :subscription, :touch=>true

class Subscription

  belongs_to  :site, :touch=>true
  belongs_to  :plan, :touch=>true
```

When you update your site.subscription.plan, this will update the subscription and the plan.

More information: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/4/20/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-touching

Comment: Unfortunately, Rails 3 doesn't appear to support touch on has_one associations (just belongs_to associations). Also, adding it to the belongs_to options you mentioned above doesn't seem to solve the problem. A pity, since it seems like an elegant approach.